# React router doesn't seen to work on production with heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, react-router

I uploaded my app on heroku. I would like `example.herokuapp.com/someRoute` to work the same as `localhost:3000/someRoute` (it works locally but not when I upload it on heroku) what should I do to make it work? I tried adding static.json file with this configuration

```
{
  "root": "build/",
  "routes": {
    "/**": "index.html"
  }
}
```

but it didn't change anything :( Any suggestions how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have a bug where you are serving the index file with **e.g.** res.sendFile from /client/public folder. Instead, on production environment you should have served it from /client/build

Please serve the file from **build** in production and **public** when in development.

**Example is this:**

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
  app.get("/*", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./client/build/index.html"));
  });
}

else {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client/public')));
  app.get("/*", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./client/public/index.html"));
  });
}
```

Comment: i think the problem is i didnt add res.sendFile at all... im not sure how should i add it since im using a controller.... this is my code 
```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/', mainController);

app.listen({port}, () => {
      console.log(`app is on port: ${port}`);
});

process.on('uncaughtException', (err, origin) => {
    console.log(err);
  })
```

Comment: and does it matter if i use public or build folder?

Comment: Yeah, it matters. Build folder is the folder that is used by heroku while in production and it is also a standard practice to do this!

Comment: my problem is that i didnt upload client folder at all to github and now i cant add it so i will have to do a new app? by the way is the code okay like this?

Comment: If you do it in the way I mentioned it will definitely works!

Comment: but i cant because i dont even use app.get like u do what i do is app.use('/', mainController) and the contoller content have nothing to do with this

Comment: Main point is that you first create build using 'npm build' or 'yarn build' then after that access that build folder in production mode and public folder in development mode using if/else condition!